# Always boot into Windows when in VM

Tags: linux, windows, boot, virtual-machine

I have a laptop that is set up to dual-boot Windows and Manjaro using GRUB2 as my bootloader. However, sometimes I want to use Windows for a little bit without closing all of my apps in Manjaro, so I am trying to set up a virtual machine that will boot up that Windows installation from my hard drive.

I got it to work with `virt-manager` and `virsh`, simply using my disk as the disk for the virtual machine. However, it is working *exactly* the same way as my normal boot process works: it shows GRUB and gives the option to select Manjaro or Windows. I want to avoid this, because if I accidentally select Manjaro while I'm also running Manjaro *outside of the VM*, it will probably brick my install.

So I created a 500MB image of an EFI system partition and installed rEFInd on it, and it successfully detects Windows on my main SSD (only after I hit backspace to refresh, which I would also like to mitigate):

[image]

But when I boot it, then Windows just goes into Startup Repair mode, then says it couldn't repair my PC. Or, it BSODs:

[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why not just give the Windows **partition(s)** instead of the whole disk to the VM and add a small virtual disk with the bootloader?

Comment: @EugenRieck I tried that, but if I only put the Windows partition in the virtual machine, then there is no bootloader (the Windows bootloader is located in the EFI system partition where GRUB is) so nothing happens.

Comment: @EugenRieck Wait, I misread what you said. Hold on, let me try that

Comment: That's what I ment by "a small virtual disk for the bootloader" ... copy your EFI partition to a vDisk and use this one

Comment: @EugenRieck How is that different from what I currently have? I already have rEFInd on a vDisk, which is my bootloader, right? If I just copied GRUB into the vDisk, then I would be back where I started (i.e., there are entries for both Windows and Manjaro present, and I only want to boot Windows in this VM)

Comment: @EugenRieck I ended up with "grub error: no such partition"

Comment: The difference being, that if you accidentially try to start Manjaro, it will be unable to and thus NOT brick your installation

Comment: You have to change a few things in the GRUB configuration, especially adapt the partitions to reflect your virtual layout (as opposed to your physical layout)